# Build docker image including version with bitbucket pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-build

I'm pretty new to Bitbucket Pipelines and I encountered a problem. I'm creating a pipeline to deploy a new version of our Spring Boot application (which runs in a Kubernetes cluster) to our test environment. The problem I encountered is the versioning of our docker build. Our versioning is set up as the following:

```
alpha_0.1
alpha_0.2
beta_1.0
gamma_1.0
gamma_1.1
```

So every minor update/bugfix increases the build number by 0.1, and a major update increases the version by 1.0 + every major update gets a new version name.

Currently I have the next setup:

```
image: java:8

options:
  docker: true

branches:
  master:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - ./gradlew test
          - ./gradlew build
          - docker build -t <application_name>/<version_name>_<version_number>
```

What is the best way to include the *version_name* and the *version_number* in the bitbucket pipeline? Until now we runned ruby script which allowed user input for version numbering, but bitbucket pipelines are not interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `alpha_0.1` etc. are tags and that the pipeline runs if a commit is tagged, you can get the tag for the current commit like this:

```
TAG=$(git tag --contains $BITBUCKET_COMMIT)
```

You can then use your favorite language or command-line tool to create the `<version_name>` and `<version_number>` from the tag you got. It may make sense to `export` the tag as a shell variable to be able to use it in a script.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the `shippable.yml` files I have, feel free to adapt it to `Atlassian`'s `pipelines.yml` and `Gradle`:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
branches:
  only:
    - master
...
build:
  ci:
    # Generates build number
    - BUILD_NUMBER=`git log --oneline | wc -l`
    - echo "Build number':' ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    # Sets version
    - mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}
    # Builds and pushes to Docker Hub
    - mvn package
    - docker login -u ${DOCKERHUB_USERNAME} -p ${DOCKERHUB_PASSWD} --email ${DOCKERHUB_EMAIL} https://index.docker.io/v1/
    - mvn -X docker:build -Dpush.image=true
```

My projects version (in `pom.xml`) are set to `0-SNAPSHOPT`

This also uses `Spotify`'s `Maven` plugin to build the Docker image instead of `docker build -t ...`

Comment: If you only need the build number, you should simply use the predefined `$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER`. (Unless you really want the *commit* number – which is what your script generates – instead of the *build* number.)